# Remove country from checkout but not from cart

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

Using the following script in wocommerce Sweden will be removed from both the cart and the checkout

```html
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) 
{
   unset($country["SE"]);
   return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```

How can I do see so its only visible in the cart when calculating the shipping price and not visible in the Checkout page?

Kind Regards,
Martin

```html
if ( is_checkout() ) { 
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) 
{
   unset($country["SE"]);
   return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );

 }
```

Doing following nothing happens when I am in checkout?

Doing following nothines happens as well:

```html
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
       unset($country["SE"]); 
    }
    return $country; 
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: you would build logic to discover the context that the function is being called from

Comment: @Scuzzy are you able to elaborate?

Comment: You could target something on the checkout page that would call your function with the filter -- rather than calling it on every page that loads.  I'm not familiar with woocommerce, but something like: `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form',  'your_filter_function' );`. Then this will only run on the checkout page, and not the cart pages.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak Are you able to share an example or share where I can read more about it?

Comment: @JeffVdovjak what in my script says that it should load on every page? Is it possible to use something like this if (window.location.pathname=='/account') {

} if so could you share how it should look like then?

Comment: @7uc1f3r Please see my update below

Comment: @7uc1f3r now no country is avaliable both in the Cart and in the Checkout hehe

Comment: @7uc1f3r I have tried again but Sweden is still avaliable in the checkout?

Comment: @Batistuta2020 your `add_filter('woocommerce_countres')` will be called every time the countries appear on a page. So you need to be more specific in your targeting.

Comment: @JeffVdovjak unfortunately is it still not working I am using is_checkout() but it does not trigger when being on the checkout page

Comment: @7uc1f3r what happend with the code snippet you posted yesterday regarding ajax?

Answer (score 0):

**This is untested as I've never worked with woo commerce -- it is offered simply as a suggestion... Hopefully this is the hook you can use.**

Your `add_filter('woocommerce_countres')` will be called every time the countries appear on a page. So you need to be more specific in your targeting.

```
// Your code to remove the country
function woo_remove_specific_country( $country ) {
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
       unset($country["SE"]); 
    }
    return $country; 
}

// Call the filter function that you already developed... but don't call it every time the countries are shown (see the function call below this function)
function woo_remove_country_filter() {
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'woo_remove_specific_country', 10, 1 );
}

// Instead of calling the filter on every page that has "countries", only call it on the checkout form
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woo_remove_country_filter' );
```